# Find number of item using prev()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You have dom like this

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="seperator">...</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
```

How do you calculate the number of items of the top and bottom section?

Comment: If using jQuery, and by "top and bottom", you mean top and bottom combined, you could get all items and exclude `.seperator`: `$("li").not(".seperator").length;` or `$("li:not(.seperator)").length;`. If you mean separately, refer to the answers below.

Comment: if you care, it's "separator".  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they're all in a single parent, there are a couple of ways. You can use `prevAll` for the ones before and look at the length:

```
var previousCount = $(".seperator").prevAll().length;
```

And for the ones after, it's `nextAll`:

```
var nextCount = $(".seperator").nextAll().length;
```

Example — note that I've changed your HTML slightly so that we don't have the same number on both sides, so we know it's working:

```js
console.log("Before:", $(".seperator").prevAll().length);
console.log("After:", $(".seperator").nextAll().length);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="seperator">...</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li><!-- I added this one -->
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: The correct spelling is "separator" (one 'e', two 'a's), not "seperator" (two 'e's, one 'a'), but I've retained your spelling in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Start at separator and use [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to get collections then use their lengths

```
var topCount = $('.seperator').prevAll().length

var bottomCount = $('.seperator').nextAll().length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prevAll() to get the preceding siblings of the element in the set of matched elements and nextAll() to get the following siblings of the element in the set of matched elements

Read : http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

and  http://api.jquery.com/nextall/

```js
console.log($(".seperator").prevAll("li").length);
console.log($(".seperator").nextAll("li").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="seperator">...</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prevAll` and `nextAll` as already mentioned in the other answers, or you can use the `index()` and get the value based on the length of the `ul`:

```js
prev = $('.seperator').index();
next = $('ul li').length - $('.seperator').index() - 1;
console.log(prev);
console.log(next);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="seperator">...</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```